# Unable to update kernel in Amazon Linux 2 as per Security Advisory: ALAS-2021-1719

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to update the kernel of an Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2 as per Security Advisory: ALAS-2021-1719. (https://alas.aws.amazon.com/AL2/ALAS-2021-1719.html)

Trouble is when I run `yum update kernel` I get a message that says `No packages marked for update`. I have checked the kernel package version I have installed using `yum list installed` and I am still on `4.14.238-182.422` when I need to be on `4.14.252-195.481` as per the advisory.

Why is `yum update kernel` not downloading and installing the latest version?

Comment: Maybe try `yum clean all;yum makecache` then run `yum update kernel` again. These two commands rebuild the cache.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  I get the same `No packages marked for update` when I try to update the kernel after running the clean al and makecache

Comment: Please run `cat /etc/os-release` and verify that you are on AL2.

Comment: Yup, am on Amazon Linux 2. I have this line`PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"` in the `os-release` file

Comment: `yum upgrade` first?

Comment: Same `No packages marked for update` with `yup upgrade`

Comment: What is your AMI id and region that you are using?

Comment: AMI: ami-0915bcb5fa77e4892 Region: us-east-1(N.Virginia)

Comment: Check with `rpm -qa|grep kernel` which versions you have installed.

Comment: This is off topic for here. You should move this over to [su] or [sf] as this place is for programming related questions...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to clean the cache first using

```
yum clean all
```

then you should update the kernel

```
yum update
```

---

**Your repositories may not be correct.**

To define a new repository, you can either add a [repository] section to the `/etc/yum.conf` file, or to a `.repo` file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. All files with the .repo file extension in this directory are read by yum, and it is recommended to define your repositories here instead of in `/etc/yum.conf`

The "yum repolist" command can be used to list installed and enabled repositories.

```
yum repolist
```

---

You should check your network firewall, Security group, subnets...

- Make sure that security group is whitelisted all inbound and outbound.
- Public subnets:

  - Make sure the route table for the public subnet is associated with this subnet
  - Route 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to internet gateway.
- Private subnets:

  - Created a NAT Gateway in a Public subnet.
  - Make sure the route table has a route 0.0.0.0/0 pointing to NAT

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **amazon-linux-extras** repository to upgrade the kernel

First, run this command to get all available kernel versions `sudo amazon-linux-extras |grep kernel`

you will see a response similar to this

```
  _  kernel-5.4               available    [ =stable ]
 55  kernel-5.10=latest       enabled      [ =stable ]
 62  kernel-5.15              available    [ =stable ]
```

the kernel version marked as **enabled** is the one installed on your machine

To upgrade to the newer version (for example, to upgrade to **kernel-5.15**), run this command `sudo amazon-linux-extras install kernel-5.15 -y`

Now, you need to reboot the server with `sudo reboot`

After rebooting, run the command `uname -r` to see the kernel version installed. It should be the same version that you chose above.

for more information, please refer to this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-linux-2-kernel-upgrade/)